# Email template - stacking elements?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've got a task to make an email template and got struck with issue where I need to stack one element on top of the other:

[image]

In regular HTML/CSS that would look like this:

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="count">6</div>
</div>

.element {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url('http://www.veryicon.com/icon/ico/System/Sticker%20Pack%201/Chat.ico') no-repeat;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #F33689;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Check [result here](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3017sm/1/)

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this result by using techniques allowed by email clients that would work in almost all clients?

What I thought I could try:

1. Negative margins (does not work in all clients)
2. Background image (does not work in all clients)
3. Position absolute/relative (does not work in all clients)
4. ...?

Thank you

Comment: why not you combined both images and use  only one..

Comment: What about `position`? `relative` to parent and `absolute` to child.

Comment: @KheemaPandey because it contains dynamic text "6" (count), then I would need to render text. I thought about it but I would like to avoid rendering different images on the go. I want to simply use one icon image and put "count" information on top of that with css styles.

Comment: @M1K1O Outlook does not support `position` (in fact Outlook does not support either of properties that I know I could try)

Comment: how you making an email via programming?

Comment: you don't have to render the image every time, just render your text into it the first time you access the image and then save it. if you use rewrite rules, you can pass parameters to your image script via url and deliver the stored image with the same url.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I'm not really sure if I understood your question, but I'm creating HTML templates with CSS styles, that's how you doo email "via programming"

Comment: @RaphaelMüller it's not literally "render every time" it's about avoiding rendering if it's possible. If it's not and I still have to make it look like in design I would generate images with numbers from 1 to 99 and simply use template in URL like "/images/messages-count-1", "/images/messages-count-2", etc...

Comment: I also created a standard HTML email in past which works well on all platform. but the thing you are trying is totally dynamic adding a dynamic counting. While making HTML template we are restricted and cannot use advance level css3 property.

Comment: I would use two images, one with red container and one without it, and use the first one when there are some notifications and the other one when there isn't.

Comment: but how @KarimAG it is a email template not a webpage?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with email template :S .. as I understand you are using html/css , can you use javascript?

Comment: and how are you getting the dynamic number of notifications ?

Comment: are you using inline-css or external .css file?

Comment: @VolkanKahyaoğlu all inline css

Comment: @KarimAG I'm using only HTML/CSS, where HTML is generated on backend and then sent to service for email dispatch

Comment: 1 more question, what do you mean "Position does not work in all clients"?

Comment: `Position: relative` or other `Position` values don't work in Outlook: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ that's why I can not make two elements overlap

Comment: I fixed the question by providing pure HTML/CSS solution that works in browsers. But I need a solution which would work in email clients as well.

Answer (score 1):

So far the only way to do it only in HTML/CSS I could come up with is to make table layout with image sliced into multiple other images and leaving "count" area as simple `<td>` where I could put any text I want:

[image]

Comment: +1 tables are something you can't avoid for design in mail templates.

Answer (score 0):

The render solution (I know you want to avoid this, but it's the one which is working in every email client)

your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^imageGenerator.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^media/cache/(([0-9]+)(.*\.(jpg|png|gif)))$ imageGenerator.php?cachename=$1&count=$2&filename=$3&type=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^media - [L]
```

and in your imageGenerator.php you can use the vars:

```
$_GET['cachename'];
$_GET['count'];
$_GET['filename'];
$_GET['type'];

//create your image and save it
```

With this mechanism in place, your requested count is generated once. After that the stored image is delivered.

In your sent HTML you can easily use:

```
<img src="http://example.com/media/cache/99-messages.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions but I already thought about this solution as a last resort one, IF it's not possible to do it with only HTML and CSS

Comment: I suggested this, because I'm aware of the different email client implementations. I have to adjust my template every time a client want something fancy in his email templates...